# eclipse 3.7.1 update error

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently using the Eclipse Indigo 3.7 IDE for Java Developers.So today I tried to update it to the latest 3.7.1 but during the update process a error downloading0 with Comparison method violates its general contract! pops out and the whole update process stucks at that process. Can someone help me with this problem?

I'm using both JDK 7x64 and JRE 7x64
[image]

Comment: Are you using a JDK7? (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317785)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Due to lack of information, I can suggest it's related to eclipse bug [317785](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317785), if you are using Java 1.7.

> Possible workarounds:
>   * use JRE6
>   OR
>   * when using JRE7, theres a small rarely documented feature
>     set system property java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
>     This should use old implementation and should not bring up the bug

Answer (score 10):

I was able to fix this problem by using this workaround taken from the link suggested by 4e6 and VonC (bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317785):

> To clarify comment #22 for those on JRE7 who can't upgrade to 3.7.1
>   because of this bug:
>
> Add the following line to your eclipse.ini:
>   -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true Then run the update to 3.7.1 from inside Eclipse again, it should succeed now. Afterwards, you should be able to drop that line from eclipse.ini again.

Comment: +1 for referencing how to get the property into Eclipse via eclipse.ini